# How do I make the secondary expanded area on my mobile menu scrollable?

Tags: css

I managed to make this mobile menu fixed via the Sticky Menu (or Anything!) plugin but the secondary expand area and more specifically the widget-area is not scrollable thus not allowing you to see all the widgets.

I’ve tried `overflow: scroll` amongst other things on various properties but I’m drawing a blank.

I expect when you expand the menu the the widget-area would become visible and you can scroll to the bottom of the widget area but you cannot, it only scrolls to a select area then continues to scroll the site body in the background.

Website: [atceg.net](https://atceg.net)

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you:
Remove `overflow-y: auto` from `.sidebar`. And add below properties to `#secondary`.

```
#secondary {
    height: calc(100vh - 106px);
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```